# Checking rotation of door

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

I have a tutorial scene set up, and at the end I have a resized cube with a door texture on it. I have set up the code to check for collisions and rotate it's pivot, but after the collision, the door rotates forever. Inside my `void OnCollisionEnter()`, I have an if statement:

```
if (pivot.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y == 83)
{
    pivot.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Could anybody enlighten me on this? As I can't seem to find the answer.

Here is the entire script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DoorOpen : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject pivot;


    void Start () {

    }

    void Update () {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision door)
    {

        if (door.collider.tag == "Door")
        {
            StartCoroutine(openDoor());
        }

    }
    IEnumerator openDoor() {

        float angle=0;
        for(int i=0 ;i<=6;i++){
            angle+= i * 10;
            pivot.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f,83f,0f);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.4f);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It may be helpful for you to include more of the OnCollisionEnter() function since the problem is likely there, and potentially some code to show how the OnCollisionEnter() is called in case the issue is actually there.
My guess, though it is entirely speculative without more context, is that the pivot.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y is never actually 83 when this check occurs, and jumps from a value below 83 to a value above 83, and therefore never freezes the rotation

Comment: @KevinWells Ah, I didn't know eulerAngles wasn't that precise. Should I instead do something like `>77 && <87`?

Comment: Now that I have more context I think I know what is going on. You are multiplying the 83 degrees by Time.deltaTime, which could mean that it will rotate for much more or less than 83 degrees. Why are you doing that multiplication?

Comment: @KevinWells I asked another question, and the answer was the `pivot.transform.Rotate(0, 83 * Time.deltaTime, 0)`, so I was using that from that answer

Comment: Nevermind my last question since it just exposes my lack of knowledge about unity. I looked it up and it seems that what you are trying to do is make the door rotate 83 degrees a second. Is my understanding correct? if so, this could still cause the problem because the total rotation may never be exactly 83 degrees. Perhaps a better way to approach this is to wait for it to pass the amount you want to have it rotate by using a >= rather than an == (specifically: if (pivot.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y >= 83)

Comment: @KevinWells I tested this in the engine, and it still rotates forever. I will try the >77 & <87 real quick.

Comment: I'm curious about if your conditional will ever be valid granted your only calling it when you Enter a collision. Have you considered placing the check in Update() or in a coroutine?

Comment: @KevinWells that seems like it would work.

Comment: @KevinWells it doesn't work. it still rotates forever, or what seems like forever

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you that you may want to use Tag to control your game better. And instead of assigning angle directly you can create a nice door animation.
using '==' operator seems unnecessary

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision door)
{

    if (door.collider.tag == "desiredTag")
    {
         StartCoroutine(openDoor());
    }

}
IEnumerator openDoor() {

  float angle=0;
  for(int i=1 ;i<=7;i++){
   angle = i * 10;
    pivot.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f,angle,0f);
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.4f);
   }

 }
```

Comment: I get the error `error CS1612: Cannot modify a value type return value of 'UnityEngine.Transform.rotation'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable` on the `pivot.transform.rotation.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f,angle,0f);` line. Any Idea why this might be?

Comment: Edited.i don't know how transform.rotation is used. i usually use transform.eulerangle.

Comment: It still does not stop the rotation, it just keeps going

Comment: Add full script something fishy going on.

Comment: Posted the entire script, hope this helps

Comment: @Joep. it should be + operator instead += and. Use this new Vector3(0f,angle,0f); you are still using new Vector3(0f,83,0f);